# How to combine mapping expressions during configuration for use in a Container

Tags: c#, automapper

Given the following code:

```
public static IMapper ConfigureMapper()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

        cfg.ShouldMapField = fi => false;
        cfg.ShouldMapProperty = pi => pi.GetMethod != null && (pi.GetMethod.IsPublic || pi.GetMethod.IsVirtual);

        cfg.CreateMap<ServiceModel.Types.NonRiskRequirement, RequiredSignature>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ApplicantFlag, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RequiredSignatureApplicantFlag))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.InsuredFlag, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RequiredSignatureInsuredFlag));

        cfg.CreateMap<ServiceModel.Types.NonRiskRequirement, NonRiskWorkItem>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.RequiredSignature, opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src => Mapper.Map<ServiceModel.Types.NonRiskRequirement, RequiredSignature>(src)))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.WorkType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WorkType));
    });

    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    return config.CreateMapper();
}
```

What is the proper syntax to get rid of the static "Mapper.Map"?, I'm using AutoMapper 5.1.1 with Autofac 4.1.1 and getting this exception back.

System.InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Hope this link is useful https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use MapFrom, use ResolveUsing. It gives you a ResolutionContext object that includes a Mapper property that you use to map, not this static way, which is not recommended, and also now broken.